# Finding a UIElement's true position when within a PivotItem

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'd like to get the on-screen position and visibility of a `TextBlock` which is embedded in a `PivotItem` - e.g. the on-screen position and visibility of `TB2` in:

```
    <phone:Pivot>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="first">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TB1" Text="Hello 1"></TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="second" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="TB2" Text="Hello 2"></TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="three" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="TB3" Text="Hello 3"></TextBlock>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

For other Xaml controls I have achieved this using code like:

```
    public static Rect Position(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        if (element.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            return Rect.Empty;

        if (element.Opacity < 0.01)
            return Rect.Empty;

        // Obtain transform information based off root element
        GeneralTransform gt = element.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);

        // Find the four corners of the element
        Point topLeft = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        Point topRight = gt.Transform(new Point(element.RenderSize.Width, 0));
        Point bottomLeft = gt.Transform(new Point(0, element.RenderSize.Height));
        Point bottomRight = gt.Transform(new Point(element.RenderSize.Width, element.RenderSize.Height));

        var left = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(topLeft.X, topRight.X), bottomLeft.X), bottomRight.X);
        var top = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(topLeft.Y, topRight.Y), bottomLeft.Y), bottomRight.Y);
        var position = new Rect(left, top, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);

        return position;
    }
```

However, for `PivotItem` children this calculation doesn't provide the expected answers when the `PivotItem` is off-screen. Instead it provides the answer of the position the item will take on-screen when the `PivotItem` is swiped back on-screen. During a transition, I can see that the position is correctly calculated using the above method - e.g. during the transition I will see the position correctly swipe in from the left/right of the screen.

I've looked through other properties like `Visible` and `Opacity` to see if there is some other mechanism being used here to hide the off-screen PivotItem or one of its `Parent`, `GrandParent`, etc - but all of those seem to yield `Visible` and `Opacity == 1.0` results.

I've also tried iterating the VisualTree to see if any element with a solid background is masking the "off-screen" `PivotItem`s - but I can't see any in the tree.

Is there some other property to consider here? How are the `PivotItem` contents hidden when they are "off-screen"? If I really have to, I know that I can use the `SelectedIndex` property of the `Pivot` to try to help with the `PivotItem` position calculations, but I'm hoping to avoid `SelectedIndex` if I can - I'd prefer to get the position using general Xaml and VisualTree methods if at all possible.

Comment: I suppose the explanation (or at least a hint) would lie in `Pivot`'s ControlTemplate.  But I can't seem to find that where I would expect it ("System.Windows.xaml").  Do you happen to know how to find it?

Comment: Creating a copy of the PivotItem ControlTemplate in the designer gives 1 in - https://gist.github.com/slodge/ba54683498ad2e2256f4 - also added at a copy of the Pivot's ControlTemplate in 2 in that same gist - https://gist.github.com/slodge/ba54683498ad2e2256f4#file-2

Comment: Those templates are pretty sparse.  I guess they do all the animations/state changes in code-behind?  Anyway, I was wrong -- not many clues there, no animations or even named parts.

Comment: Very likely you'll find your answer with this tool (21 days demo is available) http://xamlspy.com/

Comment: Mind if I ask what are you trying to achieve (why do you need this info for the off-screen pivot item)? Also, why aren't you just using the topLeft point in that method (without all those Math.Min)?

Comment: It's not that I need this info for the off-screen items. It's more that I want my method to return the position correctly for all items. The `Math.Min` calculations are necessary in the case that a rotation has been applied to the UIElement.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it, but I can't find how they are hiding the PivotItems. I guess the position is correct, but the item is just not drawn for unknown (to me) reasons. I'll look into it again, later, but for now I wanted to mention a few other potential issues I noticed.

1. Shouldn't you be using Math.Max for the bottom right corner? Reason being - ActualHeight and ActualWidth are not rotation-aware so to speak.
2. RenderSize.Width/Height and ActualWidth/Height are different. I'm not sure it's a good idea to use both of them for the calculation.
3. Don't you need to check everything in the visual tree above the element to see if it's actually visible?

**Edit:** I looked at Microsoft.Phone.dll's decompiled source (that's the dll with the Pivot control), and I couldn't find anything about how the PivotItems are hidden. There are some native method calls though.

Comment: Thanks for the research and points. Still considering 1 and 2 -I'll need to do some prototyping to confirm. On 3, this is already taken care of in my "real" code - it just didn't make it into the simple code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some Changes to Your code and its giving UIElement's true position

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot">
            <phone:PivotItem Header="first" x:Name="first">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TB1" FontSize="30" Text="Hello 1" Tap="TB1_Tap"></TextBlock>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="second" x:Name="second">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TB2" FontSize="50" Height="66" Width="155" Margin="20" Text="Hello 2" Tap="TB2_Tap"></TextBlock>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="three" x:Name="three">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TB3" Text="Hello 3"></TextBlock>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

CS:

```
public partial class PivotPage1 : PhoneApplicationPage

{
    public PivotPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void TB1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect r = Pos.MyPosition(TB1,first);
        string str = "Left" + r.Left.ToString() + "\nTop:" + r.Top.ToString() + "\nRight:" + r.Right.ToString() + "\nBottom:" + r.Bottom.ToString() + "\nHeight:" + r.Height.ToString() + "\nWidth" + r.Width.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }

    private void TB2_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect r = Pos.MyPosition(TB2,second);
        string str = "Left" + r.Left.ToString() + "\nTop:" + r.Top.ToString() + "\nRight:" + r.Right.ToString() + "\nBottom:" + r.Bottom.ToString() + "\nHeight:" + r.Height.ToString() + "\nWidth" + r.Width.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}

public static class Pos
{
    public static Rect MyPosition(FrameworkElement child,FrameworkElement parent)
    {
        if (child.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            return Rect.Empty;

    if (child.Opacity < 0.01)
        return Rect.Empty;

    // Obtain transform information based off root child
    GeneralTransform gt = child.TransformToVisual(parent);

    // Find the four corners of the child
    Point topLeft = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    Point topRight = gt.Transform(new Point(child.RenderSize.Width, 0));
    Point bottomLeft = gt.Transform(new Point(0, child.RenderSize.Height));
    Point bottomRight = gt.Transform(new Point(child.RenderSize.Width, child.RenderSize.Height));

    var left = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(topLeft.X, topRight.X), bottomLeft.X), bottomRight.X);
    var top = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(topLeft.Y, topRight.Y), bottomLeft.Y), bottomRight.Y);
    var position = new Rect(left, top, child.ActualWidth, child.ActualHeight);

    return position;
    }
}
```

[image: Sample Screen Capture 1]
[image: Sample Screen Capture 2]

Comment: Thanks. Except for changing the parent I can't see any other difference in your code - is there something I'm missing? Also, just to clarify: I'm looking to get the position of `TB1` relative to the screen correctly reported when `TB2` is tapped. Currently the code in the question reports that `TB1` is in an "on-screen" location when `TB1` should really be off the side of the screen somewhere.